# Are some varieties of Paulownia sterile?

Tags: trees

Is it true that some varieties of Paulownia are sterile? And if so, where are they sold?

Answer (score 3):

[Pollarded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollarding) trees do not produce flowers, as these only form on mature wood. However this is a labour intensive solution.  If you plant an invasive variety and stop pollarding you have gifted the neighbourhood with a problem.

Answer (score 2):

There is a species listed as non invasive, although they produce seeds. [*Paulownia elongata*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paulownia_elongata), a fast growing tree with many various uses. Sources may rise and fall, but [Amazon](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=paulownia%20elongata&source=productsearch&cd=1&docid=17659901848724792857&ved=0CD0QgwgwAA&url=http://www.amazon.com/BEAUTIFUL-PAULOWNIA-Paulownia-elongata-seeds/dp/B007368H7M&ei=NDKIT8_wL8iEgwei3O32CQ&usg=AFQjCNEDfctSukUDnmctuJWtFuLdX36qjA) is currently selling it.